# C struct pointers return

Tags: c, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 100   

typedef struct config_struct config_t ;

struct config_struct{
    char name[20];
        char ip[20];
        int port;
        char log[100];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        config_t config;
        read_config_file(argv[1], &config);
        return 0;
}

int read_int_from_config_line(char* config_line) {
        int val = atoi(config_line);
        return val;
}

void read_str_from_config_line(char* config_line, char* val) {
        strncpy(val,config_line, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);
}

void read_config_file(char* config_filename, config_t *config) {
        FILE *fp;
        char *value, buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
        fp = fopen("./settings.conf", "r");
        while (fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, fp) != NULL) {
            if(!strcmp(buffer,"NAME")) {
                    read_str_from_config_line(value, &(config->name));
        }   
            if(!strcmp(buffer,"PORT")) {
                &(config->port) = read_int_from_config_line(value);
                }

        }
}
```

I try to compile this code and it gives me a incompatible pointer type at read_str_from_config_line(value , &(config->name)); and lvalue required as left operand of assignment  &(config->port) = read_int_from_config_line(value);

I am trying to return the stuct back to the main program but I'm having problem with the struct pointers.

Any solution for it to be solve? 
PS: The code is a mess as I trying to shorten it. Any help will be good as I am still a beginner to C programming.

Thanks

Comment: If you use array as left operand of `=` without `[]` operator it is automatically 'casted' into pointer to first element of the array. Try it without `&` operator, because it returns R value pointer to pointer value (I guess).

Comment: @nikachx you can not assign to an array.

Comment: Both errors can fixed by removing `&`.

Comment: 1) `if(!strcmp(buffer,"NAME")) {` --> `if(!strcmp(buffer,"NAME\n")) {`

Comment: @KamiKaze Ok, I think you are right.

Comment: 2) `read_str_from_config_line(value, &(config->name));` --> `read_str_from_config_line(value, config->name);` and Using uninitialize variable as `value`.

Answer (score 2):

```
                read_str_from_config_line(value, &(config->name));
```

confg->name is declared as a `char` array, which naturally decays to a pointer to the first element (of type "pointer-to-`char`") if you omit the `&`:

```
                read_str_from_config_line(value, config->name);
```

Taking its address explicitly instead results in a pointer of type pointer-to-array-of-20-`char`s, which is not the same type as pointer-to-`char` - which is why you are getting an error. This is a common source of confusion in C; in general, you should not take the address of an array (although it does have legitimate use cases).

In this line:

```
            &(config->port) = read_int_from_config_line(value);
```

You are taking the address of the `port` member of the structure pointed at by `config`, which is a non-lvalue pointer. It looks like you are actually trying to assign to the member, so the line should read:

```
            config->port = read_int_from_config_line(value);
```

Comment: alright thanks. what if i would like to printf config.name? How should i do it ?

Comment: So in the whole code i'll use config->name instead of config.name for everything that i will do related will struct now?

Comment: @JimYong If you have a pointer to a struct, access its members using `->`. So in your `read_config_file` function, use `config->name`, yes.

Comment: ok thanks. problem now is at`config->port = read_int_from_config_line(value);`
it's not reading to config->port.

Comment: @JimYong You are not intialising the `value` pointer that you are passing as an argument. Are you compiling with warnings enabled? You should have got a warning about that I think.

Comment: @JimYong I mean that you declared the variable, but didn't assign a value to it. Then you tried to use the value (that it didn't have...) in an expression.

Comment: ah i see..but how do i go about of fixing it? I dont see where didnt i assign a value to it.

Comment: @JimYong this is a problem with the logic of your program that can't be explained in a series of comments here. You never assign a value to the pointer; there is no expression that looks like `value = (something)`. As to what the value should actually be, that's complicated. Maybe ask a separate question. Try to restrict your question to one straightforward question. Right now it seems like your understanding of C just isn't good enough to be writing a program like this.

Answer (score 2):

The `&` operator means "take the address of the object to the right".

This:

```
&(config->port)
```

means "take the address of the `port` member of the structure pointed to by `config`.

You don't want to take the address, you just want to assign to the member. That's just:

```
config->port = ...
```

This is the same as `(*config).port`, but nobody writes it like that since the arrow operator is so convenient.